# Capital and Lower case

Tags: java, string, uppercase, lowercase

Im writing a program that holds the alphabet on a string. Along with this, I'm adding scanner that allows the user to input a character. When the user inputs their character it tells them what letter of the alphabet it is by using the charAt(index)
. I've gotten all this to work. The only thing I'm trying to get is the display to tell the user if he/she entered an upper case or lower case letter. Any clues on how I can do this?

Comment: Not sure if this si what you want or not, but you could have a look at [`Character@isUpperCase`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/Character.html#isUpperCase-char-) (there's also a `isLowerCase` equivilent)

Answer (score 2):

You can use [`Character.isLowerCase()`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/Character.html#isLowerCase-char-) and [`Character.isUpperCase()`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/Character.html#isUpperCase-char-) to check an individual `char`.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `Character.isUppercase(Character toCheck)`

Answer (score -2):

Java have two string manipulation methods called `toLowerCase()` and `toUpperCase()` that do exactly what they sound like.

Comment: OP does not want to convert characters. He wants to determine if it is upper or lower case.

Comment: Is there a way I can post a picture of my code other than rewriting it on here? Mike has hit the nail on the coffin for what I want to determine. But how do I determine that? Thanks for all your input from everyone, really. I appreciate it.